# How to use 'OpenCppCoverage' for existing source code of C language?

Tags: c, visual-studio, code-coverage

how to open the existing C source code project of multiple folders and how to test the code coverage for selective C files by using the OpenCppCoverage plugin in Visual studio 2017?

What are the steps? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I think this question is better asked from Google, research and understanding are your own. You have to try first on your own then put up a question if necessary. Welcome to SO community.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very good documentation on how to use OPENCPPCOVERAGE on already exists code:

[SETTING UP OPENCPPCOVERAGE WITH VISUAL STUDIO](http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~rusu/oop/demo/Code_coverage.pdf)

Comment: http://www.cs.ubbcluj.ro/~rusu/oop/demo/Code_coverage.pdf URL not found